# SFTP GUI +SSH Key

Tags: ssh, sftp

Is there any application that allows connecting via SFTP using private keys rather than password?

I know that I can do that via Nautilus, but I would prefer some standalone application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would try [FileZilla](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/filezilla).

```
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

It proved to be reliable and feature-rich for me.

Here is the Wiki page on how to [SSH2 keybased authentication](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto#SFTP_using_SSH2:_Key_based_authentication) works.

Comment: because of UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 bug I didn't see Filezilla menus, but I found proper options in Filezilla settings. Tnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Octavian Damiean says (since `FileZilla`'s `sftp` [description](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto#SFTP_using_SSH2%3a_Key_based_authentication) wasn't helpful to me), I'm successfully using it with sftp, some of findings are as follows:

- set public key to filizilla via "Settings --> Connection --> SFTP" (FZ converts the file into .ppk file and asks where to store).
- Create server setting for the server you're connecting to via "File --> Site Manager".

  - Port: (can be blank)
  - Logon type: Interactive
  - User: the one that you use with ssh from commandline

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Another GUI for mounting and managing a remote file system is gigolo

```
sudo apt-get install gigolo
```

Run gigolo

```
gigolo
```

Choose type of connection (FTP, Obex, SSH, WinDav or Windows Share). Enter URL, User ID and Password for remote server. The remote file system shows up as a folder under "Network" in the local file browser.